# Очистка консоли

Tags: c++

Как очистить экран консоли без подключения библиотек???

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду "без подключения библиотек"? Вы без них и вывести-то ничего не сможете.

Comment: @Vasya Можете сделать так system( "cls" ); Вместо cls можете использовать ту команду OS, которая очищает экран.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow это ведь требует <cstdlib>

Comment: @Vasya Да, требует.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ну так, а мне нужно без

Comment: @Vasya "Без" вы ничего не сделаете, так как любая функция требует подключение библиотеки.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow а если с помощью iostream?

Comment: @Vasya Это тоже функция, (класс с методами) объявленная в <iostream>

Comment: @VladfromMoscow что ЭТО?

Comment: @Vasya А я почём знаю?

Comment: А без библиотек печатать пробелы можно ? может просто пробелами заполнить :)

Comment: @Mike, костылеориентированное программирование, люблю такое :D

Comment: Боюсь, вам все равно придется дергать системные вызовы. Уж не знаю, считается это "без библиотек" или нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  system("cls");
  return 0;
}
```

Для win:

```
void clear() {
    COORD topLeft  = { 0, 0 };
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screen;
    DWORD written;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &screen);
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterA(
        console, ' ', screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
        console, FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_BLUE,
        screen.dwSize.X * screen.dwSize.Y, topLeft, &written
    );
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, topLeft);
}
```

Для *nix:

```
void clear() {
    std::cout << "\x1B[2J\x1B[H";
}
```

[Тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/) можно посмотреть другие известные варианты очистки экрана консоли.

asm вариант для особо одаренных:

```
PUSHA ;
XOR EAX, EAX ;
XOR EBX, EBX ;
XOR ECX, ECX ;
XOR EDX, EDX ;
MOV AH, 6 ; 
MOV DX, 174fh ;
INT 10h ;
POPA ;
```

Данный вариант не будет работать в защищенном режиме.

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: @Vasya это стандартная библиотека которая является базовой для языка. Не вижу причин не использовать ее, если конечно, у вас не стоит цель поизвращаться :)

Comment: именно такая цель, просто подключать для 1 функции не хочу

Comment: Еще раз, это стандартная библиотека. Отказ от ее использования ничего вам не даст, даже наоборот.

Comment: Даст -1 строку кода как минимум

Comment: @Vasya: А как вы собираетесь использовать `cout` без библиотек?

Comment: @VladD я же про очистку консоли спрашиваю, может можно без cout, но в любом случае это лучше чем std, т.к. iostream используется гораздо чаще мной

Comment: то есть с использованием iostream можно, а с cstdlib нельзя? хочу узнать логику, почему так.

Comment: @Vasya /o\ подключение стандартной библиотеки никак не отразится на результате компиляции так как это инструкция для компилятора(в конкретно этом случае)

Comment: по ссылке не нашёл способа без подключения библиотек

Comment: @Vasya скажите, а как вы собрались писать в консоли, без подключения библиотек? :)

Comment: @Bezarius ну ладно хватит придираться как с помощью iostream тогда?

Comment: @Bezarius ответ gbg подошёл бы, но у меня не работает

Comment: @Vasya вообще то, у меня предложен аналогичный вариант :) Если хотите совсем без библиотек, воспользуйтесь asm.

Comment: @Bezarius о это лучше спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой бякой

```
cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H";
```

Здесь две команды - почисти экран `\033[2J`

И переведи курсор в левый верхний угол `\033[1;1H`

Comment: Ну это если консоль поддерживает ESC-последовательности.

Comment: Чего-то не работает

Comment: @VladD как выяснить это?

Comment: @Vasya: А какая у вас ОС? Если Windows, то не поддерживает. Если какая-то из разновидностей Юникса, то с хорошими шансами поддерживает.

Comment: @VladD windows, а другие способы тогда есть?

Comment: @Vasya: Ну, для Windows есть в другом ответе.

Comment: @VladD там вроде std нужен